# How does direct3d manage the storage of resources for different usage?

Tags: memory, graphics, gpu, direct3d, video-memory

I'm using direct3d and dxgi to write a VNC program and I want to minimize the resource transfer between the Video RAM and System RAM. But I'm confusing by the some part of the following code. Since the usage of texture acquired by the method **AcquireNextFrame** is not staging and cannot be read by CPU, I have to copy it to a staging texture. But I'm wondering what does the **CopyResource** do when it copies from a default usage resource to a staging usage resource? Does it allocate some memory in Video RAM for the staging resource, then copy to that area and when I call **Map** the texture is copied from that area to the System RAM or it directly copies resource to the System RAM?

```
DUPL_RETURN DUPLICATIONMANAGER::GetFrame(D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE* rawBits, bool* Timeout) {

IDXGIResource* DesktopResource = nullptr;
DXGI_OUTDUPL_FRAME_INFO FrameInfo;

// Get new frame
HRESULT hr = m_DeskDupl->AcquireNextFrame(0, &FrameInfo, &DesktopResource);
if (hr == DXGI_ERROR_WAIT_TIMEOUT)
{
    *Timeout = true;
    return DUPL_RETURN_SUCCESS;
}
*Timeout = false;

if (FAILED(hr))
{
    return ProcessFailure(m_Device, L"Failed to acquire next frame in DUPLICATIONMANAGER", L"Error", hr, FrameInfoExpectedErrors);
}

// If still holding old frame, destroy it
if (m_AcquiredDesktopImage)
{
    m_AcquiredDesktopImage->Release();
    m_AcquiredDesktopImage = nullptr;
}

// QI for IDXGIResource
hr = DesktopResource->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<void **>(&m_AcquiredDesktopImage));
DesktopResource->Release();
DesktopResource = nullptr;
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    return ProcessFailure(nullptr, L"Failed to QI for ID3D11Texture2D from acquired IDXGIResource in DUPLICATIONMANAGER", L"Error", hr);
}

ID3D11Texture2D* StagingTex = nullptr;
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
m_AcquiredDesktopImage->GetDesc(&desc);
desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
desc.BindFlags = 0;
desc.MiscFlags = 0;
hr = m_Device->CreateTexture2D(&desc, nullptr, &StagingTex);
if (FAILED(hr)) {
    return ProcessFailure(m_Device, L"Failed to create texture for extracting raw data", L"Error", hr, SystemTransitionsExpectedErrors);
}

m_DeviceContext->CopyResource(StagingTex, m_AcquiredDesktopImage);
UINT subresource = D3D11CalcSubresource(0, 0, 0);
**hr = m_DeviceContext->Map(StagingTex, subresource, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, rawBits);**
if (FAILED(hr)) {

}
m_DeviceContext->Unmap(StagingTex, subresource);
StagingTex->Release();
return DUPL_RETURN_SUCCESS;
```

}

Comment: The answer is: That's up to the driver. In practice, it's usually a DMA transfer by the GPU over the PCIe bus to the system memory.

Comment: Thank you very much. But that means in some cases it is copied twice from Video RAM to Video RAM and then mapped to System RAM, right? If so, is there a way I reduce the first copy? That copy is a waste of time.@ChuckWalbourn Walbourn

Comment: If you need CPU access, you can create the texture as DYNAMIC usage and then Map it directly, assuming you control the original texture creation.